# How to write a file in to an OS X app Resources folder?

Tags: c++, macos, fstream

I have an xcode project, the used language is C++. while my program is running writes a txt file in to

`My App.app/Contents/Resources/`

folder using fstream. After a month pause don't work anymore. Nothing is modified on the project but the OS X is updated. The file path is ok, i can read the file. What is wrong?

Comment: Can you report the file i/o error that your code gets?

Comment: at the point where you open the file for writing or write the data, get the error code from the file operation.

Comment: no errors shown on output.

Comment: You might have to modify the code to see the file error. Can you show the code?

Comment: `ofstream x;
 x.open("Data/usr.txt");
if (!x.is_open()) {
cerr << strerror(errno);
}

if (!x.good()) {
cerr << strerror(errno);
}
`

Comment: Set a breakpoint at cerr < strerror(errno); and see what errno's value is.

Comment: Now shown the error on the output: No such file or directory"

Comment: but i can it open with if stream..

Comment: That is strange! I agree with @trojanfoe though, you should try moving the files to your application support folder. The answer he posted below is correct.  Modify the code to use that folder. Also check for applications capabilities in the project settings. Make sure Sandbox is OFF.

Comment: Sandbox is OFF. I use c++ and SDL. How can i create an own folder in application support for my app to save my data?

Comment: It's complicated but you can test the concept by hard coding. Your application support folder is called  /Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Application Support/APPLICATIONBUNDLEIDENTIFIER/ and you can make a test file in there by hand. You can find the application bundle identifier in the project settings under Build Settings then Packaging. In my work it is like com.creativemedicalsystems.myApplicationName  So you can either make usr.txt right in there, or make a folder called Data and put it in there. The path then needs /Data/usr.txt after your application name.

Answer (score 0):

You should not write into your app bundle, and instead use one of the following folders to store files, which can be obtained using [`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains):

- Document folder (`NSDocumentDirectory`).
- Application Support folder (`NSApplicationSupportDirectory`).
- Caches folder (`NSCachesDirectory`).

If you write to your app bundle you will cause issues with the code signing of the app and might not even have write access, if it's installed in the default location (`/Applications`).

Comment: also don't works If i use absolute path ("/Users/me/something.txt") i think my program has no permission to write a file

Comment: Is the app sandboxed?

Comment: I don't know, im new in xcode. how can i check this?

Comment: It's in the capabilities of the target editor.  See the image on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013839-CH35-SW1).